# Why simple subtraction of two sets is not working?

Tags: xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I have following xml file. I need to find members are in $c which are not in $v:

```
(C) - (V) = desired result


let $c := /transport/trips/trip
let $v := /transport/trips/trip
where (data($c/@vehicle)="PKR856") 
return
<result2>
        {$v/(from|to|through)/string()} 
        {$c/(from|to|through)/string()} 
</result2>
```

Now I wan to subtract them and here is my code:

```
let $c := /transport/trips/trip
let $v := /transport/trips/trip
where (data($c/@vehicle)="PKR856") 
return
<result2>
    { $c/(from|to|through)/string()[not(. = $v/(from|to|through)/string())]} 
</result2>
```

I have tried this also is not workoing:

```
let $c := /transport/trips/trip/
let $v := /transport/trips/trip/(from|to|through)/string()
where (data($c/@vehicle)="PKR856") 
return
<result2>
    { $c/(from|to|through)/string()[not(. = $v)]} 
</result2>
```

output:

internal error code, argument

**EDIT**

Here is the XML file:

```
  <trips>
  <trip driver="d2345" vehicle="PKR856" date="12-DEC-2007">
    <from>London</from>
    <to>Newcastle</to>
    <through stop="1">Leicester</through>
    <through stop="2">Nottingham</through>
    <time>1</time>
  </trip>
  <trip driver="d6767" vehicle="UUQ007" date="10-MAY-2008">
    <from>Paris</from>
    <to>Rome</to>
    <through stop="1">Lyon</through>
    <through stop="2">Milan</through>
    <time>15</time>
  </trip>
  <trip driver="d2345" vehicle="PKR856" date="14-DEC-2007">
    <from>Paris</from>
    <to>Amsterdam</to>
    <through stop="2">Brussel</through>
    <through stop="1">Mons</through>
    <time>4</time>
  </trip>
</trips>
```

I need to return name of cities has not been visited by specific vehicle number?

I have tried these but is not working:

```
let $driver-cities := /trips/trip[@vehicle="PKR856"]/(from, to, through)/string()
return /trips/trip/(from, to)/string()[not(. = $driver-cities)]
```

I actually change the answer to:

```
let $c := /transport/trips/trip/(from|to|through)/text()
let $v := /transport/trips/trip[@vehicle eq "PKR856"]/(from|to|through)/text()
return
<result>
            { $c except $v} 
</result>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example document? Also `$c` and `$v` are identical, so `$c except $v` will always be empty. Is that different in your original query?

Comment: @LeoWörteler I have edited and added my XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `except` operator to gain the difference of your two sets. Perhaps something like the following would work for you:

```
let $c := /transport/trips/trip
let $v := /transport/trips/trip[@vehicle eq "PKR856"] 
return

    $c except $v
```

Although as one of your sets is the complete set of all `trip` elements, the following produces the same result, and seems simpler to me:

```
/transport/trips/trip[@vehicle ne "PKR856"]
```

In collaboration with @Bernard, I believe the simplest desired answer is:

```
let $x := /transport/trips/trip[@vehicle ne "PKR856"]/(from|to|through)/text()
return
    <result>{$x}</result>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is returning trips which is not done by specific vehicle. My concern is name of cities is not visited by specific vehicle.

Comment: This is probably what I need but I get error:
$c/(from|to|through)/string() except $v/(from|to|through)/string()

Comment: You get an error because `except` operates on sequences of nodes and not on sequences of atomic types (e.g. strings).

Answer (score 0):

In [XQuery 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/) you can use the [`group by` clause](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-group-by) to find all vehicles that a city has been visited by. This can then be used to filter the results for those cities not visited by a specific vehicle:

```
let $vehicle := 'UUQ007'
for $trip in //trip
let $curr-vehicle := $trip/@vehicle/string()
for $city in $trip/(from, through, to)/string()
group by $city
where not($curr-vehicle = $vehicle)
return $city
```

This returns `London Newcastle Leicester Nottingham Amsterdam Brussel Mons` for your example document. If you set `$vehicle := 'PKR856'`, the result is `Rome Lyon Milan`. I tried this in the newest version of [BaseX](http://basex.org/).

If your processor does not support XQuery 3.0, the following query is probably less efficient but computes the same result in XQuery 1.0:

```
let $vehicle := 'UUQ007'
for $city in distinct-values(//trip/(from, through, to))
where not(//trip[@vehicle=$vehicle]/(from, through,to) = $city)
return $city
```